# React Native- How to access .csv files in my project hierarchy

Tags: reactjs, csv, react-native

I am trying to load a CSV file in my js class and I am unable to do so in react native. This file is available locally. Not downloaded. Whenever I give a path to the CSV file, I get an error that says The module could not be found. No such module exists. I have tried placing the CSV in various folders and also at my project root level. It does not work. I noticed images do not face the same problem.

I have even tried doing this.

https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths/

Again it works for images but strangely not for CSVs.

I have tried the import statement, require statement and even relative path for the files. Same error every time.

I am new to react maybe I am missing some step?

EDIT: Two of the ways I tried

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import Papa from 'papaparse';
import CSVData from './CSVData.csv';

function loadAllCSV()
{
 console.log('Loading CSV');
 var path = './CSVData.csv';
 console.log(path);
 const fileContents = RNFS.read(path);
 console.log('File Data ' + fileContents);
 Papa.parse(CSVData, {
   download: true,
   delimiter: '\t',
   complete: function(results) {
      console.log('ZOMBIIIIEEEE');
      console.log(results);
    }
   });
}
```

Error:
Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(Unable to resolve module `./CSVData.csv` from `/Users/abc/xyz/SearchPage.js`: The module `./CSVData.csv` could not be found from `/Users/abc/xyz/SearchPage.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- `/Users/abc/xyz/CSVData.csv(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
- `/Users/abc/xyz/CSVData.csv/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)` (null))

Comment: Please add your code and the error you are receiving, it might be related to a react module.

Comment: Edited the question above. Thanks Tom.

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: @Manish I posted what worked below..

Answer (score 0):

Adding the .CSV files to the project assets bundle in iOS fixed this problem for me.

Use Xcode to place the files in the project in the Project Settings under the Build Phases Tab check if the Assets are included in the Copy Bundle Resources Section. Add the files to the list here incase they are missing.

Comment: I use RNFS to write a new CSV file and would like to open it to display the data. I tried react-native-doc-viewer which does the work on Android but doesn't help me in iOS. Any suggestion on how to do this on iOS? I am open to any kind of workarounds.

Comment: Please how do I add the CSV file to iOS? Thank you